# IntelliJ does not flag Java 11 features when using Java 10 language level

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

I have a project in IntelliJ IDEA that is compiling with JDK 11 but targeting Java 10 language level.

My problem is that IntelliJ allows me to use, even suggests in autocomplete, Java 11 features like `Optional#isEmpty`.

There's no indication that I've done anything wrong until I build and the compiler complains.

Since I am targeting Java 10 language level, I would have expected that IntelliJ not offer Java 11+ features.  Is there a setting I'm missing, or are my expectations too high?

---

In Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project:

Project SDK is 11 and Project Language Level is 10.

All modules have their Language level set to *"Project default (10 - Local variable type inference)"*.

In Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler:

Project bytecode version is 10 overall, and for each module.

In Gradle I have:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_10
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-183.4284.148

Comment: Does changing the target language level affect module dependencies? I thought it only flagged new language constructs provided by the compiler, opposed to hiding potential module or classpath dependencies that may not be available/wasn't released with that version

Comment: Just in case you have a specific *module setting* as well, you can update the question with that too.

Comment: Also, what is your precise IntelliJ version? Is it the latest [IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (183.4284.148)](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2018.3+%28183.4284.148%29+Release+Notes) one?

Comment: @nullpointer do you mean specific module setting in the Project Settings dialog?  Those are all set to inherit from the project setting.  Edited to include that and exact version number (which is the latest).